# Avoiding duplicates when adding cells in column one by one

Tags: google-sheets

How can I have a kind warning if I am adding a text to the cell which was already added somewhere in previous cells of the same column?

Comment: Did you had the time to evaluate my solution?

Answer (score 3):

I prepared the following solution.

### Formula

*Not case sensitive*:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:A)>COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A));"Invalid";"Names")
```

*Case sensitive*:

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(LOWER(B2:B)))>ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(UNIQUE(LOWER(B2:B))));"Invalid";"Names")
```

### Explained

If you set conditional formatting in `A1` on `Invalid` to be marked `red`, then a visual change will make you realize that a duplicate value has been entered, see pic:
[image]

In combination with Google Apps Script, you can really make it more visual. With the following script, that uses the onEdit trigger function, you can make the font color turn red:

### Code

```
function onEdit() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var cell = sh.getActiveCell();
  var A1Notation = columnToLetter(cell.getColumn()) + '1';
  var color = sh.getRange(A1Notation).getValues() == "Invalid" ? 'red' : 'black';
  cell.setFontColor(color);
}

// stackoverflow.com/a/21231012; Adam Luske
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[Avoiding Duplicates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdC1SeVF0cDI1eUNEZEdqOXVMeFBQckE)**.

### Note

- you need to fix the headers, in order to keep seeing visual change (without using the script).
- you need to pay attention, because all of this isn't bullet proof !!

Comment: Nice solution. I really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be with Data validation (under Data). Assuming the unnamed column in question is ColumnA, a Custom formula validation rule of:

```
=countif(A:A,A1)=1
```

[image: WA29823 example]

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

The little red triangles are the warning signs.